# Not able to connect to Internet via proxy in Tizen emulator

Tags: proxy, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

When i use ajax code to retrieve a json data, in tizen wearable emulator 2.3.1, I'm getting **not able to connect to proxy** error.

> But when I searched, everyone is telling no need to give any specific
>   proxy settings for emulator. If internet works fine in Tizen ide, then it will
>   work in Tizen emulator too. But I'm getting proxy error.

Can someone help me solve this proxy error?

Update:

[image]

Where should I change the proxy?

Code sample:

```
 $.getJSON( "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON? north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo", function( data ) {
                  $('#divText').html(data.result);
                })
                .fail(function( err ) {
                    //Never called
                    console.log( err );
                });
        }
```

Comment: Can u share sample code?

Comment: Just a normal ajax call or xmlhttp request

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add internet access privilege for your Tizen application in the **config.xml** file.Internet Privilege allows the application to access the Internet.

```
    <tizen:privilege name="tizen.org/privilege/internet"/>
```

Also defining external access Policy may be required to access network. According to the W3C Access Requests Policy (WARP), you cannot access external network resources by default. If you require access to an external network resource, you must request network resource permissions for the Web application using the Policy in the **config.xml** file.

```
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

Now your application should be able to access internet from the **emulator** as well as **real devices**.

Comment: I've already given the privilege. But the proxy is blocking it. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 1):

In the emulator's configuration set the proy as use host proxy and the connect type as NAT then to access your local server use 10.0.2.2 as IP address

Comment: Can you help me in setting proxy for this emulator? Because i couldnt find any configuration to set proxy.