# Leaflet and Samsung Gear Frontier S3 (Tizen Studio)

Tags: leaflet, tizen-web-app

Is it possible to use leaflet on a tizen wearable as web-app?
I'm looking for examples.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Download the Leaflet- latest version zip file and unzip.
- Create Tizen-Studio Wearable Web Project.
- Copy the leaflet.js into js folder and leaflet.css into css folder.
- Include the js, css files in html.

For Accessing Internet from a Tizen Web app you would need 'Internet' privilege and remote resource 'access' policy in config.xml. Check out [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783743/not-able-to-connect-to-internet-via-proxy-in-tizen-emulator/37960903#37960903)

Now you may follow the guidelines on popular blogs and Official Leaflet site.

https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/2017-12-04-add-mapping-with-leaflet/

https://medium.com/@franpix/adding-a-leaflet-map-to-a-jquerymobile-web-app-b525491df520

https://leafletjs.com/examples.html

I've tested Map init on Tizen Wearable Emulator...

[image]

Comment: Works perfekt! Thank you.